# Redirect ALSA device to Windows

Tags: ssh, alsa, ssh-tunnel

I am writing some programs using very simple/low-level ALSA audio output,
essentially doing something like:

```
snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
snd_pcm_set_params(handle, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S32, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED, width, sampleRate, 0, (width * NUM_PERIODS_PER_BUFFER * MICROSECONDS_IN_SECOND) / sampleRate);
```

and then, in a loop:

```
snd_pcm_writei(handle, buff, frames.frames_in_period);
```

This works as expected playing sound on local (Linux) loudspeakers.

Since this Linux machine is a headless server I need to move "somewhere else" (together with loudspeakers,of course) and access it through `ssh` (MobaXTerm on windows, actually) making it impossible to hear output.

Question is: is there a simple way to redirect audio over ssh tunneling?

I have seen [`trx`](http://www.pogo.org.uk/%7Emark/trx/), but it seems to be unavailable on windows.

It would be very important to avoid modifying playing program (changing output device is OK)

Comment: Have a look at *pulseaudio* and/or *jackd*!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub : AFAIK neither have a Windows port, did I miss something?.

Comment: Here is an old thread under Linux Mint, about sharing sound between linux and window: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=160527

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/371687/how-to-carry-audio-over-ssh - in any case I think you might get more help on https://superuser.com/